# WPF Binding Property With Recursive Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm presenting a tree structure via a TreeView. As it is unknown how deep the tree will be, I'm using a recursive HierarchicalDataTemplate.

In the following code I'm Databinding to an external Object Tree

```
public class Tree : ObservableCollection<Node> {}
```

This works fine:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Tree}}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type src:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

But when I try to bind to a Property

```
public ObservableCollection<Node> LocalTree{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Changing the first line of the XAML to

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding LocalTree}">
```

The TreeView stays empty.
What am I doing horribly wrong?

Comment: Maybe instead of ObservableCollection<Node> put Tree in "public ObservableCollection<Node> LocalTree"

Comment: The Tree object was only for testing purposes and has no other usage, i.e. I'm really interested in displaying  ObservableCollection<Node>; The property LocalTree represents 1-level Children.

Comment: You changed `{Binding Source={StaticResource Tree}}` to `{Binding LocalTree}`. Why not `{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalTree}}` ? May be your binding are wrong?

Comment: {Binding Source={StaticResource XXX}} is a way to bind to external Objects. In my Project i have other instances of using a TreeView where I have properties which are bound to directly by ItemsSource="{Binding XXX}" and everything works fine.

Comment: So, if you change type of `LocalTree` from your C# code in question from `ObservableCollection<Node>` to `Tree` it works? Unbelievable :)

Comment: @Yuri Dorokhov no, you have misunderstood me. I have other situations where I'm binding a TreeView to a Property "public ObservableCollection<Node> CollectionOfNodes{}" via ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfNodes}" and everything works fine. The Tree class is not needed and will be deleted, was just for testing.

Comment: If you have a working example already, then just compare your current code to that and find the difference(s). It's probably a simple binding or data error... look in your Output Window in Visual Studio to find your error(s).

Comment: That's the problem  - even after multiple comparisons I cannot find the error.